# Length of items by field in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get the number of objects that contain a certain value from an array?

Using `componentDidMount` to get stored data in a Firestore `db` as

```
componentDidMount() {
 db.collection(`company/${this.props.userID}/campaigns`).onSnapshot(collection => {
  const campaigns = collection.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  this.setState({ 
    campaigns,
   });
 });
}
```

This mounts the data in `this.state` but I would like to get the count value for each by their `status` field. Here is an example below whereas I am trying to get the `length` of entries for `status` = `active` `draft` `paused`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      campaigns: [{
          id: 1,
          status: "draft",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          status: "active",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          status: "draft",
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          status: "paused",
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    const totalCampaigns = this.state.campaigns
    const activeCampaigns = this.state.campaigns.filter(campaign => campaign.status === "active")
    const draftCampaigns = this.state.campaigns.filter(campaign => campaign.status === "draft")
    const pausedCampaigns = this.state.campaigns.filter(campaign => campaign.status === "paused")
    return (
      <div>
        total {totalCampaigns.length}
        Active {activeCampaigns.length}
        Drafts {draftCampaigns.length}
        Paused {pausedCampaigns.length}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Could you please help me understand what I am doing wrong or if there is a better method for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `reduce` method on `state.campaigns` and return an `object` where the keys will be the `status` and the value will be the number of occurrence of the status

```js
let state = {
  campaigns: [{
      id: 1,
      status: "draft",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      status: "active",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      status: "draft",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      status: "paused",
    }
  ]
};

let getCount = state.campaigns.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(curr.status)) {
    acc[curr.status] = 1
  } else {
    acc[curr.status] += 1

  }

  return acc;


}, {})
console.log(getCount)
```

```
render() {
    const totalCampaigns =  // here goes the the getCount
    return (
      <div>
         Active {getCount.draft}
        Drafts {getCount.active}
        Paused {getCount.paused}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I think my issue is in fact not the question stated as I get similar results   in `TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined` whereas before it was `filter` of undefined. I think it is more so to do with the array itself. I will paste it above and perhaps you could have a look to why it is undefined?

Comment: Either way, accepted the answer because it's spot on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below code

```
campaigns_1 = campaigns.reduce(function(acc, cur){
    if(!acc[cur.status]) { 
      acc[cur.status] = []
    }
    acc[cur.status].push(cur);
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Now **campaigns_1** will be of the form of

```
    {
       "draft": [ {
         "id": 1,
         "status": "draft"
       },
       {
          "id": 3,
          "status": "draft"
       }],

       "active": [{
           "id": 2,
           "status": "active"
       }],

       "paused": [{
           "id": 4,
           "status": "paused"
       }]
    }
```

Now to get how many elements are there with status as **draft** you can use

```
const = no_of_draft_campaigns = campaigns_1.draft.length;
const = no_of_active_campaigns = campaigns_1.active.length;
const = no_of_paused_campaigns = campaigns_1.paused.length;
```

**One benifit you will have is when you will want all the elements with a particular status you can get that by**

```
const draft_campaigns = campaigns_1.draft;
const active_campaigns = campaigns_1.active;
const paused_campaigns = campaigns_1.paused;
```

You can check a working example here

[image: Edit GitHUb_Cards_ReactJS]